# Как оцифровать изображения дата-сета в Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, dataset

**Имеется:** папка с цветными картинками одинакового размера (256x256), всего таких картинок 115. Необходимо создать Pandas DataFrame, в котором были бы все оцифрованные картинки. Вот пример (как я представляю) датафрейма Pandas с одной картинкой размером 2х2:

```
pandasDataframe([(0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 0)])
```

Здесь создан список для этой одной картинки, а каждый кортеж представляет собой RGB-значение пикселя. И по итогу этот Pandas DataFrame должен будет передаваться методу `fit` модели классификации.

**Проблема:** для оцифровки я использую такую функцию:

```
def digitize_dataset_images():
    for file in listdir(DATASET_IMAGES_DIRECTORY): # Идём по всем картинкам в папке
        filename, extension = splitext(file)
        try:
            if extension == ".png":
                # Открываем картинку с помощью PIL
                im = Image.open(DATASET_IMAGES_DIRECTORY + "\\" + filename + extension)
                # Проходимся по каждому пикселю и заносим (пока его в dataframe)
                for pixel in iter(im.getdata()):
                    print(pixel) # здесь пока нету добавления пикселя в dataframe, просто пример
        except OSError:
            print("Cannot digitize %s" % file)
```

Дело в том, что помимо того, что данный код выполняется неимоверно долго на моем ПК, но он еще и возвращает странные значения, а именно что-то по типу этого (дело не в нулях, а в том, что кортежи содержат четыре значения, что не сходится с RGB-значением, да и всё равно не понятно, зачем здесь такие кортежи):

`((0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0) ...)`

**Комментарий:** помогите, пожалуйста, оцифровать мои картинки так, чтобы я смог избежать проблем, описанных выше (то-есть, чтобы полученный оцифрованный dataframe был годен для скармливания модели классификации. Тип модели я пока не определил, но пусть это будет KNN)

Answer (score 0):

могу подсказать по скорости - сам с этим сталкивался: сначала (в цикле) данные rgb закинуть в список, а уж потом весь список одной командой загнать в датафрейм. Операция займет секунды. 
Почему 4 значения вместо трёх: не знаю... я обычно  картинку закидываю в пиксельную матрицу pix = image.load()  и потом пробегаю двойным циклом ...
 pix[i,j][0] - красный

 pix[i,j][1] - зеленый

 pix[i,j][2] - синий